# In Rails model check if URL on same Rails server exists

Tags: ruby-on-rails, url, dragonfly-gem

In a Rails model how can I check if a URL on the same Rails server exists?

I'm using dragonfly and am trying to check the existence of an image from a path such as `/media/BAhbBlsHOgZmIikyMDExLzExLzIxLzEwXzNxXzQyXzI5NF9Wb3NraG9kMi5qcGc`

FileTest.exists? won't work because I don't have the file path and I can't open the URL because I don't have the server hostname.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can get hostname from controller.

```
request.host
request.host_with_port
```

Comment: Thanks I can pass the host from the controller as an argument to the model method. However I'm finding this doesn't work because the server will hang and timeout.

Comment: Yep I was in development, thanks, it works on my production server. _However_ due to caching on the server this won't accurately tell me if an image exists or not... so I'll need to come up with something else to solve this.

Comment: Can't you bypass cache by adding some dummy query parameter, /media/BAhbBlsHOgZmIikyMDExLzExLzIxLzEwXzNxXzQyXzI5NF9Wb3NraG9kMi5qcGc?no_cache=1

Answer (score 0):

Did you try using `RAILS_ROOT`?

```
FileTest.exists?("#{RAILS_ROOT}/public/#{filename}")
```

Comment: Thanks but this won't work because it requires a path to the actual file on the server, which I don't have (see original post).